# Configure IIS to use Active Directory authentication

Tags: active-directory, iis-7.5

I have hosted a website on a server within the Enterprise network. The website needs to be accessible from machines(PC/Mac) in the network as well as from devices like tablets outside the network(through VPN). Now, i have a mandate to use only Active Directory authentication to access the website. How do i configure the IIS to use/prompt Active Directory credentials while accessing the site?

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is what you want to configure. Domain joined PCs will automatically send their credentials, other devices will be prompted for credentials.

You will need to turn off other authentication methods to ensure the user authenticates.

Comment: I have turned on the Windows Authentication and configured the web app to use windows authentication. The issue being, the app is expecting username/password from the server local user directory and not the Active Directory.

Comment: Is your server joined to your domain? Lot of troubleshooting steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387156/unable-to-get-windows-authentication-to-work-through-local-iis